# Logic doesn't work after .then

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a Login end point that respond me a json. 
I'm using vue-router to do a POST and then Store a token in localStorage, but after the POST, the json shows on the screen:

```
{"success":false,"message":"Login ou senha inválidos!"}
```

It should return on the page login, with the *message*

This is the code:

```
var vmLogin = new Vue({
el: '#login',
data: {
email: '',
msg: '',
password: ''
},
beforeCreate: function () {
 if(localStorage.getItem("timeTaskToken") !== null) {
  window.location.href = '/'
}
},
methods: {
getLogin: function (e) {

  this.$http.post('/login', {email: this.email, password: this.password}).then((response) => {
    alert('teste!');
    if(response.body.success === true) {

      localStorage.setItem("timeTaskToken", response.body.token);
      window.location.href = '/'
    } else {
        this.msg = response.body.message
    }


  }, (response) => {
    // error callback
  });
  e.preventDefault();
}
}
});
```

**login page**

```
<form id="login" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
 <h3>{{ msg }}</h3>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
 <div class="col-sm-10">
  <input type="email" v-model="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <input type="password" v-model="password" class="form-control" name="password"  placeholder="Password">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
   <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" @click="getLogin">Sign 
  in</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </form>
```

It's like nothing after **.then** works...

The returned JSON just appear in the screen.

Comment: Can we see the template in `#login`?

Comment: @Bert done! 321

Comment: It looks to me like you want `if(response.body.message.success === true)`.

Comment: console.log(response); gives me nothing...

Comment: Ah so your `alert` isn't even firing?

Comment: @Bert No. It isn't

Answer (score 1):

I expect the problem is that the Sign In button is a `submit` button and you just want it to be a `button` button.

Change

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" @click="getLogin">Sign in</button>
```

To

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" @click="getLogin">Sign in</button>
```

Note the `type="button"`.

If you leave it as type `submit` then the form is is actually posted and code execution will stop. This also explains why you see a page that has just the JSON result; that is just the response from posting that form.

Alternatively, move `e.preventDefault()` to the top of the method.

You could also use `@click.prevent="getLogin"`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a console.error in you error callback

```
}, (response) => {
    console.error(response);
  });
```

This is the first step because maybe you just enter here ..

Comment: console.log(response); gives me nothing...its like the code don't get there...ignoring `then`

Comment: Hum Yeah , maybe an idea, just change this 

    getLogin: function (e) {


To this 

    getLogin: (e) => {

Because you use this with refere to not the global scope , you maybe have to bind you this .